# How to change the attribute of subitem are used by `use` element?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I learn SVG. I want to change the circle `fill` value of the second `use`. How can I do it? This is my attempt:

```css
* {
 stroke: brown;
 stroke-width: 1;
 fill: none;
}

.canvas{
 border-color: green;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.sun > circle{
 fill: yellow;
}

.hot-sun > circle {
 fill: red;
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/css' href='../css/index.css'?>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='1400' height='1000' viewBox='0 0 1400 1000' class='canvas'>
 <title>SVG learning</title>
 <desc>This is my sandbox</desc>
 <defs> 
  <g id='foo' class='sun'>
   <rect x='0' y='0' width='50' height='50'/>
   <circle cx='25' cy='25' r='10'/>
  </g>
 </defs>
 <g id='dwg'>
  <use xlink:href='#foo' transform='translate(10 10)' />
    <!-- Here I expected my sun will be red...-->
  <use xlink:href='#foo' transform='translate(10 70)' class='hot-sun'/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using <use> for this. Just draw the shapes you want in the colours you want.

Comment: I want to use the `foo` group many times with different `fill` values (and of radius values, for example). Later if it will be necessary I change the `foo` definition in one place and it would be updated for each `use`. It is like for AutoCAD block definitions.

Comment: use isn't really designed to work like that. It's designed to show one item lots of times.

Comment: Is exist something that can do what I meant?

Comment: draw lots of individual items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot CSS-select sub-elements of a use element, as they are not part of the DOM. Nonetheless, CSS-attributes for the use element itself can be inherited. So, as long as you do not style the referenced element defined in `<defs>`, the styling of `<use>` will prevail.

Note that there must not be a `* { fill:...}` rule. It would style the `defs > #foo > circle` element, and that would take precedence over the inheritance from the `use` element. This is why the stroke of the second sun remains brown, despite the rule I have defined to paint it green.

```css
* {
 stroke: brown;
 stroke-width: 1;
}

#foo rect {
 fill: none;
}

.canvas{
 border-color: green;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

use {
 fill: yellow;
}

.hot-sun {
 fill: red;
 stroke: green
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/css' href='../css/index.css'?>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='1400' height='1000' viewBox='0 0 1400 1000' class='canvas'>
 <title>SVG learning</title>
 <desc>This is my sandbox</desc>
 <defs> 
  <g id='foo' class='sun'>
   <rect x='0' y='0' width='50' height='50'/>
   <circle cx='25' cy='25' r='10'/>
  </g>
 </defs>
 <g id='dwg'>
  <use xlink:href='#foo' transform='translate(10 10)' />
    <!-- Here I expected my sun will be red...-->
  <use xlink:href='#foo' transform='translate(10 70)' class='hot-sun'/>
 </g>
</svg>
```